# Find max value based on ending values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that is similar to the one below:

| Name | Current submission | Submission | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 43-01 | 43-01 | 1-1-2019 |
| A | 43-01 | 42-01 | 1-1-2020 |
| A | 43-01 | 42-02 | 1-1-2021 |
| A | 43-01 | 42-03 | 1-1-2022 |

I want it to look like the following:

| Name | Current submission | Submission | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 42-03 | 43-01 | 1-1-2019 |
| A | 42-03 | 42-01 | 1-1-2020 |
| A | 42-03 | 42-02 | 1-1-2021 |
| A | 42-03 | 42-03 | 1-1-2022 |

Here is the code I used to get the first table:

```
SELECT 
   Submission, 
   MAX(Submission) over (partition by Name) as [Current Submission], 
   Date
FROM Table_Name
```

I have tried to do a `CASE WHEN` statement using `MAX(Date)` but I can't get the logic right...

Comment: *I can't get the logic right...* - which you haven't explained. What is the logic? Are you expecting integer sorting on a *string* column?

Comment: What is the column format of Submission?

Comment: @Isolated it is nvarchar

Comment: And why is 42-03 greater than 43-01? Is that because it's based on time?

Comment: @Stu I want to find the max string value, based on the most recent date. I assumed using a CASE WHEN statement and MAX(Date) would be all I needed, but the code I have tried is not giving desired table.

Comment: I think perhaps the problem is you keep saying MAX. The MAX string value would be 43-01. I think what you really want is the most recent value for Submission. Most recent and MAX are very different concepts.

Comment: `first_value(Submission) over (partition by Name order by "Date" desc)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was literally writing this when the last comment was made.

```
select name, 
first_value(submission) over (partition by name order by date desc) as current_submission, 
submission, 
date
from my_table
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to shawnt00 with the following solution

```
SELECT
   Submission,
   FIRST_VALUE(Submission) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DATE DESC),
   DATE,
FROM Table_Name
```